# Book about our first space battleship using 105mm howitzers and 30mm autocannon to retake our Mars mining colony from the alien black triangle ships

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a sci-fi book where there were these powerful and ruthless aliens who recorded themselves ripping our miners' helmets off and transmitted these atrocities live, prompting Earth to react by building three of our first-ever battleships using off-the-shelf current military hardware (targeting radar, 105mm howitzers, 30mm vulcan autocannon). The story goes on to explain the first crews and the problems with disease (colds/flu) spreading rapidly throughout the ships. The story also accounts for our first (fairly successful) counterattack launched from these battleships in Earth orbit. The battleships eventually reached Mars.

I'm getting a REALLY fuzzy recollection of the cover art as a black, triangle spacecraft. The clincher I really remember was that these prototype battleships we built had the weapons platforms on the exterior of the ship, and they didn't know if the wires holding them in place would work. The targeting computer/telescope could track the enemy but only knew where the shells landed by the shells exploding, so they could "walk" the detonation point until the target was hit. I also clearly remember almost the entire first crew being waylaid to sickbay or being killed outright by our own viruses.

Comment: When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: read the ebook on my Nook ~22 years ago

Comment: i'm getting a REALLY fuzzy recollection of the cover art as a Black, Triangle Spacecraft

Comment: the clincher i really remember are these protype battleships we built had the weapons platforms

Comment: on the exterior of the ship & they didn't know if the guy wires holding them would wotk. the targeting computer/telescope could track the enemy but only new where the shells landed by the shells exploding so they could "walk" detonation point ujtil the target was hit. also clearly remember almost the entire 1st crew was waylaid to sickbay or killed outright by our own viruses

Comment: THANX 4 HELPING, EVERYONE! I'VE BEEN TRYING TO FIND THIS TITLE FOR several YEARS

Comment: NOW I HAVE HOPE AGAIN SOMEONE WILL KNOW THE TITLE